# De google sheets a DataFrame usadondo requests + pd.read_html

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Necesito usar la librería *requests* para un desafío y no estoy obteniendo el resultado deseado.

```
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
datosArgentinaBiblotecasPopularesURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udwn61l_FZsFsEuU8CMVkvU2SpwPW3Krt1OML3cYMYk/edit#gid=1605800889'
r = requests.get(datosArgentinaBiblotecasPopularesURL)
data = r.content
df = pd.read_html(data)
df[0].shape
(100,28)
```

Ese shape retorna solo 100 filas, pero está mal. Usando este código:

```
sheet_url = datosArgentinaBiblotecasPopularesURL
url_1 = sheet_url.replace("/edit#gid=", "/export?format=csv&gid=")
df2=  pd.read_csv(url_1)
df2.shape
(2017,25)
```

El segundo bloque de código funciona correctamente, pero no es lo que me piden.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que dé el mismo resultado equivalente usando *requests*?

Comment: Por que no te sirve el segundo bloque de código? Simplemente podés quedarte con esa url, ya que nunca va a cambiar (a menos que cambie la hoja de calculo) y ya tenés la vida solucionada. Estaría bueno que expliques por que no es lo que te piden para poder darte respuestas acorde a lo que te piden.

Comment: Hola Dante, gracias por responder. No puedo usar el segundo bloque de código porque estoy haciendo un desafío en el cual me piden usar la librería requests.

Comment: De nada! Si haces en el segundo bloque `r = requests.get(url)` y luego `content = r.content` vas a obtener en la variable content una cadena de bytes que es totalmente compatible con el método read_html de pandas. Por lo que tecnicamente estás usando requests. Igual ten en cuenta que en un escenario real, te conviene más usar el segundo bloque de código sin alterar, pues así dejas que Pandas se encargue. En lo personal, no le veo mucho sentido a dicho desafio.

Comment: Sobre por que falla el original, tengo una teoría (no soy experto). Creo que para evitar cargar toooooda la hoja de calculo Google solo te pasa una parte. Conseguí antes hacer un truco en base a esto donde con un bucle iba seleccionando cada 100 celdas y funcionaba bien (aunque usa muchas request, por lo que es lento y te podrían bloquear). Pero me parece mejor mi primera propuesta.

Comment: Dante, Pude resolverlo! por algún motivo google limita la cantidad de celdas, tenes razón, la solución es esta: 
URL ORIGINAL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PS2_yAvNVEuSY0gI8Nky73TQMcx_G1i18lm--jOGfAA/edit#gid=514147473
URL MODIFICADA: 
'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PS2_yAvNVEuSY0gI8Nky73TQMcx_G1i18lm--jOGfAA/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&gid=514147473'

URL A MODIFICAR: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&gid=idhoja